# Incorrect delete vote count in tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

The count of delete votes needed to delete a post is not always displayed correctly in the tooltip. This is what happened when I found this bug:

- I was in the "delete" tab in the tools, and it said that a question needed 2 votes to delete.
- I navigated to the post, and the tooltip of the "delete" link said this:

[image]

- And after voting to delete it, it wasn't deleted, now it says that it needs one more delete vote (which is then the correct number).

This appears also to be the case for other questions that need two delete votes.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I see variants of this question all the time. What do you think happened between the time that you loaded the page and the time that you voted to delete?

Comment: @Rusher I think there happened nothing.

Comment: Well I think that someone else retracted their delete vote while you were pondering whether to cast yours.

Comment: @Rusher You cannot retract delete votes.

Comment: Did you previously delete vote that question and then press the back button and try to cast another vote?

Comment: @Rusher No, I didn't, and it also happens for other questions which I didn't delete vote.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233537/218012

Comment: [Fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236417/361699)